# How to change a custom SVG icon color to be compatible with theme provider in Materiel-UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have 2 icons one is a classic icon imported from Mui , the other is a custom logo.svg , the problem is I want to be able make those 2 icons compatible with theme switch using theme provider, if the theme is dark then icons should change colors from dark to white I managed to do this with the imported icon by adding color='primary' , but the problem is the stubborn custom svg, did any one had this issue ?

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  icon: {
    fontSize: 35,
    //color: 'grey',
    '&:hover': {
      //color: 'white',
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    },
  },
}));

const iconStyle = {
  padding: 2,
  marginTop: 0,
  marginBottom: 0,
  //backgroundColor: '#ef6c00',
  borderRadius: '50%',
  //fill: '#222222',
  //fill: 'grey',
  '&:hover': {
    color: 'white',
  },
};

 // Custom svg icon
 <Logo style={iconStyle} width='60' height='60' />
 // Mui icon compatible with theme provider. 
 <EmojiObjectsIcon color='primary' className={classes.icon} onClick={switchTheme} />
```

[image: Codesandbox Example]

Comment: Code doesn't work. There is no clarity on specifics

Comment: it is a chunk from react.. app, i will make a codesandbox then..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two steps to achieve the goal.

First, find a way to pass color to a `svg` icon.

Second, use the `pirmary` color and `theming` options for the icon.

##### First

By creating a `Logo` component and using the `svg` on it:

```
const Logo = ({ fill, width, height }) => (
  <svg
    fill={fill}   // ---> here
    width={width}  // ---> here
    height={height}  // ---> here
    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  >
    <path
      d="M17.707 8.293a1 1 0 0 1 0 1.414L15.414 12l2.293 2.293a1 1 0 0 1-1.414 1.414L14 13.414l-2.293 2.293a1 1 0 0 1-1.414-1.414L12.586 12l-2.293-2.293a1 1 0 1 1 1.414-1.414L14 10.586l2.293-2.293a1 1 0 0 1 1.414 0z"
      fill={fill}  // ---> here
    />
    <path
      clipRule="evenodd"
      d="M22 5a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H9.46a2 2 0 0 0-1.519.698l-5.142 6a2 2 0 0 0 0 2.604l5.142 6A2 2 0 0 0 9.46 20H21a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V5zm-2 13H9.46l-5.143-6L9.46 6H20v12z"
      fill={fill}  // ---> here
    />
  </svg>
);

export default Logo;
```

It's like your other components, the `fill` and other props are passed to it.

Now, we have a `Logo` component (with .jsx extension) as same as other components with some props on it.

##### Second

Now time to add `Logo` icon to the `AppBar` and pass the related color props:

```
<Logo
  fill={
    theme
      ? darkTheme.palette.primary.light
      : darkTheme.palette.primary.dark
  }
  width="16"
  height="16"
/>
```

You may also need to pass the `width` and `height` property with the `Logo` component.

Working version on [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-firefly-x7ghg?file=/src/AppBar.jsx).

Answer (score 3):

To make a custom SVG icon behave like other @mui/icons-material, make use of the SvgIcon component from mui.

If you are having multiple custom icons, its better to create an index file in the assets/icons folder and do the following.

```
import {SvgIcon} from '@mui/material'

export const CustomIcon = (props)  => <SvgIcon {...props} viewBox="0 -960 960 960">
// <path ... fill='inherit'/>
// <path ... fill='inherit'/>
// <rect ... stroke='inherit'/>
</SvgIcon>
```

In page, you can use it as simply as

```
<IconButton><CustomIcon color='primary'/></IconButton> //or any theme
```

The important things to remember here is to remove the svg element that comes along with the svg file when you copy the path. Only the elements excluding the svg are required. If the icon is not showing, ensure the viewbox in the original <svg> was passed to the <SVGIcon>.

**To make the color change as other mui icons, replace all the custom color of fill property in paths to "inherit". This makes the icon take the color its provided by the theme provider**